# Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have this warning in my console, when I use ***nextJs Link*** component. Can you help me solve this problem and explain me why.

here is the console message

[image]

here is my piece of code

```
import React from "react";
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'

import logo from '/public/Images/E2R5_white.png';


const Logo = () => {

    return (
        <div className="">
            <Link href="/">
                <Image
                    src={logo}
                    height="50"
                    width={"80"}
                    alt="Logo - E2R5"
                />
            </Link>
        </div>)
}

export default Logo;
```

Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 7):

The quick solution is to use `<a>` tag inside `Link`.

```
 <Link href="/">
   <a>
      <Image src={logo} height="50" width={ "80"} alt="Logo - E2R5" />
   </a>
 </Link>
```

Useful link to read: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component

Comment: Thanks for that link. I tried this but ended up then deciding to bail on using `Link` at all: `const LogoLink = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LogoLinkProps>(
  ({ onClick, href }, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLAnchorElement>) => {
    return (
      <a href={href} onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
        <Logo className="max-h-8" />
      </a>
    );
  }
);
LogoLink.displayName = "LogoLink";`